# How to hide the 95% CI on the forest plot

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am trying a way to hide the information we see on the right side of the forest plot (ES(95% CI).
I am using the metafor package in R.

The code is as follows

```
library(metafor)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))

res <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR",
           slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "), method="REML")

forest(res, xlim=c(-16, 6), at=log(c(0.05, 0.25, 1, 4)), atransf=exp,
       ilab=cbind(dat.bcg$tpos, dat.bcg$tneg, dat.bcg$cpos, dat.bcg$cneg),
       ilab.xpos=c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5), cex=0.75, ylim=c(-1, 27),
       order=order(dat.bcg$alloc), rows=c(3:4,9:15,20:23),
       xlab="Risk Ratio", mlab="", psize=1)
```

Could not find this option in the manual. Anyone was successful?

Comment: Use `annotate=FALSE`.

Comment: @Wolfgang Please post as an answer.

Comment: @Wolfgang By the way, I created [tag:metafor] tag, and there are lots of [metafor question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+metafor), thank you for the package!

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for adding the tag!

Comment: How to remove 95%CI for the forest plot function from meta package. I find annotate=F doesn't work for forest function in meta package

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the "annotations" by using argument `annotate=FALSE` in `forest()`. Take a look at `help(forest.rma)`.

Comment: How to remove 95%CI for the forest plot function from meta package. I find annotate=F doesn't work for forest function in meta package